# Using DOMDocument PHP

Tags: php, domdocument

I have managed to drill down to the element that I want. Here is an example of the html markup

```
<p> <strong> Title foo </strong> foo bar foo bar </p>
```

Is there a way to check if the string of a node contains `<strong>` or `<b>` etc? Is there a way to do this with DOMDocument or would I have to implement an xpath solution??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if the string of a node contains or etc

Try looking at the [`textContent` property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) of the node.  Watch out, `textContent` searches both the node and all descendants.  If you need a precise match and don't want to crawl the tree yourself, then a xpath solution would probably be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to check whether the string you are looking for is included in the content of the node.

Comment: [No no no no no.  N͍̰̜̯̯ͥ͆͒͠óͯ͗̂ͅ.͚̰̗̬̱͎͋͂̈́̊](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).